# 301 Redirect to change structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been researching redirects for a few days now and am still struggling, so I decided to post my first question here. For some reason, it is just not clicking for me.

I have redesigned and developed a client's WordPress site and need to update it's structure.

The site's current structure is:
www.domain.com/blog/postname/2011/12/26/

The new structure should be:
www.domain.com/blog/postname

I really thought this was going to be easy since all I am looking to do is drop the date, but have not been able to grasp the whole wildcard aspect and how to end what I am trying to match. Any help would be greatly appreciated. A simple answer is great, but an explanation would be even better.

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you already know how to change your  WordPress permalink structure to drop the date.

To 301 redirect all of the old URLs to the new ones, add the following rules to your .htaccess file in the root of your websites domain, ahead of any existing rules that are there.

```
#if these 2 lines already exist, skip them and add the rest
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if there is a request of the form /blog/post-name/yyyy/mm/dd/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/blog/[^/]+/)[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/$ [NC]
#redirect the request to the URL without the date
RewriteRule . %1 [L,R=301]
```

If you want to learn more about .htaccess/rewriting you can take a look at the following urls: [Indepth htaccess](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/), [Brief Introduction to Rewriting](http://ulrichpalha.com/myblog/2011/11/26/improve-your-sites-seo-with-basic-url-rewriting-redirects-using-mod_rewrite-in-htaccess/), [Apache Mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Let me know if this works for you and/or you have any issues.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much.

I was trying to do it without a RewriteCond which was obviously incorrect. I really appreciate your time and the links to other resources.

Thanks again and Happy Holidays!

Bart